Record Page Component Limit
While working on a record page I got the following error:

I searched the web and scoured the official Salesforce documentation - but the only thing I can find are some posts in the Trailblazer community from people who encountered the same error. I cannot find anything else regarding this limit. Is it missing from the documentation? Does anybody know more about this? Can I give my users some good recommendations when building record pages?

Recommendation: reduce the number of components to be less than 250.

Haha. Yes. I meant something like - why are users even adding that many components, I wonder? Am I the only one getting this?

The official documentation talks about one region with 100 component limit but i could not find about total limit on page. check here: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.lightning_page_components.htm&type=5
one reason i can think of users adding these many component is visibility of components. Admin would wants to have a centralized page for multiple line of business.

Yeah. I found multiple other limits while searching but none of them was about the limit mentioned in the error message. How strange.

I work at Salesforce but have nothing to do with this area, but have the benefit of seeing the codebase
The error message is pretty clear - 250 is a limit for the number of components on a page.
Looking at the history - you can see why this might've not been documented. A couple years ago, the error message used to be

This page is too complex. Simplify it and try again

It seems this was purposefully more vague to hold the ability to have the "too complex" calculation change (other than pure number of components). Though, it was/seems to have been always checking the number of components and was done more for resource protection. Worth noting the 250 number was picked many years ago (2017) and probably seemed like a number that was unlikely to be reached.
If you truly think 250 is not enough, as flexipages have obviously changed a lot in features, I would put a case in to at least get that either:

Documented
Known to the product owner that somebody wants more than the 250 limit. They may even be interested in seeing what that flexipage is doing.

It might end up with a Salesforce "idea", but it's the best way to get it on their radar.

Thanks for the insights—this is incredibly valuable and precisely what I was looking for. I think that 250 components is plenty, so I see no need to change this. I appreciate your feedback!
